# How to deactivate maven profile in child module?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I have a profile defined in parent `pom.xml` and activated by property. In child module I need to de-activate it. How this can be done (it's Maven 3)?

ps. As far as I know it can't be done legally ([MNG-4565](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4565), [MNG-5083](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5083)), but what is a possible workaround?

Answer (score -3):

It depends. Child poms should not deny parent pom behaviour (it's like [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for build process). It may be a good idea to define profile in a parent pom, but activate it only in child poms where you really need it.

If you can't do it, you could activate profile in a parent pom by a property with exact value:

```
<profiles>
  <profile> 
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>environment</name>
        <value>test</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

and then redefine property value in a child pom.

Comment: Redefining of the property in child pom.xml won't have any effect, since Maven builds effective pom **before** reading its properties.